# How to get all the metrics of an instance with prometheus api?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I want to fetch the monitor host's metrics through the api of prometheus, and I need to initiate a request for each metric requested.

```
curl http://IP:9090/api/v1/query?query=node_cpu_seconds_total{instance="IP:9100"}

curl http://IP:9090/api/v1/query?query=node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{instance="IP:9100"}
```

Is there a way to request all the performance data from the monitoring host at once?

Answer (score 6):

You can fetch all metrics with following curl expression:

```
url=http://{urIPorhostname}:9090    
curl -s  $url/api/v1/label/__name__/values | jq -r ".data[]" | sort
```

Answer (score 2):

All the metrics for a particular instance `IP:9100` can be obtained via the following PromQL query:

```
{instance="IP:9100"}
```

This query returns all the metrics, which have the given `instance="IP:9100"` label. See [time series selector docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors) for more details. See also [PromQL tutorial](https://valyala.medium.com/promql-tutorial-for-beginners-9ab455142085).

The `{instance="IP:9100"}` query can be sent to the following Prometheus querying APIs:

- [/api/v1/query](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#instant-queries) - this endpoint returns matching time series values at the given timestamp specified via `time` query arg. For example, `curl 'http://prometheus:9090/api/v1/query?query={instance="IP:9100"}'`
- [/api/v1/series](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#finding-series-by-label-matchers) - this endpoint returns matching time series without any data, e.g. only metric names and labels are returned. For example, `curl 'http://prometheus:9090/api/v1/series?match[]={instance="IP:9100"}'`
- [/api/v1/query_range](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#range-queries) - this endpoint returns calculated datapoints for matching time series on the selected time range `[start ... end]` with the given `step` interval between samples. See more details about calculated datapoints in [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#staleness).

If you want returning just unique metric names without labels, then you can query [/api/v1/label/**name**/values](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#querying-label-values) endpoint: `curl http://prometheus:9090/api/v1/label/__name__/values`  . The `__name__` is a special label name used in Prometheus for referring to metric names. Note that multiple time series may share the same metric name. For example, `http_requests_total{path="/foo"}` and `http_requests_total{path="/bar"}` time series share `http_requests_total` metric name, while they differ by `path` label values.

Answer (score 1):

You can request all current node_exporter metrics from a specific machine with the following command:

```
curl --request GET "http://NODE-EXPORTER-IP:9100/metrics"
```

Comment: Hi Marcelo, running your command doesn't seem to work as the api returns a "Method not Allowed" message

Comment: It works like a charm to me (I just tested again).

Comment: @GeorgeFandango, did you used the IP from the machine which is running the Node Exporter?

Comment: Hi Marcelo, I managed to test your command once again and it worked. Error was I was pointing to the wrong prometheus server. thanks a mill!

Answer (score 0):

### USE API

and watch out! if you config nginx for proxy to prometheus.

then

u have to do like this: curl http://localhost:9090/**prometheus**/api/v1/query?query=up
-------------------------------------extra nginx-config in the url.